# Why is Graphics2D drrawing diferrent sized images with the same code in different environments

Tags: java, image

I have a requirement for generating images from the pages of pdf files so it can be processed by a legacy application that will send them to a very specific printer.

I have written some code to convert the pages in the ***.pdf*** file to ***.png*** files using a mix of pdfbox and awt. Below is the code adapted for publishing here:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.ImageType;
import org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer;


public class ImageConverter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {     
        String pdfFilePath = "input_folder";
        String imageFilePath = "output_folder"; 
        int width = 1540;
        int height = 2200;
        float dpi = (float) 299.3;
        PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(pdfFilePath));       
        convertPdftoPng(document, imageFilePath, width, height, dpi);   
    }

    private static void convertPdftoPng(PDDocument document, String imageFilePath, int width, int height, float dpi)
            throws IOException {        
        PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
        
        for (int page = 0; page < document.getNumberOfPages(); page++)
        { 
            BufferedImage outputImage = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(page, dpi, ImageType.RGB);
            ImageIO.write(outputImage, "png", new java.io.File(imageFilePath + "00" + (page + 1) + ".png"));
        }
        document.close();
    }
}
```

Now, while testing the code, I found an odd behaviour, where depending on the environment the code runs, the output file has a different resolution (x and y pixels), based on the DPI.

When running on my windows machine, with DPI 299.3, the output is 1540 x 2204, which is close to the intended result, whilst to achieve a similar resolution in our KaaS environment, DPI needs to be 186, to achieve a resolution of 1537x 2197.

Now, on my machine, I'm running this with eclipse bundled JVM (Java 19), and the project is configured to run on Java 11.

On the server, which is running inside a Kubernetes pod with tomcat, where we're running the code for testing purposes, the JVM is running Java 11 (OpenJDK).

edit. Additionally, this code is to be run on the backend. There is a file listener for the input_folder, that will start the pdf processing (as soon as another system uploads the file through sftp) and output the images. There is no user interaction for this.

Any suggestions on what might be causing the difference on the resolution and how I can address it?

Comment: Maybe this? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getScreenResolution--

Comment: The code in the server is run by a backend process, without any user interaction (basically, we use a file listener and process the pdf to output the images). Can you elaborate on how using this method can help me out?

Comment: Isn't `outputImage` already in the right size right after being returned from `renderImageWithDPI(...)`? Why are you drawing the image into itself?

Comment: @K J   when I try using DPI = 186, on my machine it is rendering as 957x1370. As for the 299 dpi, I used an online tool to calculate the dpi from the pixel width and height with an 8in page size and then adjusted it through empirical testing.

Comment: @matt, I have already removed that from my code. updated the code in the question as well

Comment: You could, create the size of BufferedImage you want. Then render the pdf to create a BufferedImage and then draw that to the BufferedImage you created. That way you know it will be the correct size. Right now it looks like the "problem" is solely with PDFRenderer, I would expect that rendering the pdf at a specified DPI should always produce the same size image.

Comment: @K J, I used float at the renderImageWithDPI takes a float dpi as a parameter and to do a fine tuning to reach the value we wanted. with it I got from 299 -> 1537 pixels to 299.3 -> 1540.